# STRING: how to get string output from this input string?

Tags: c#, regex, string, web-services, api

How do you get the message from the following inputs

Input is formated by field name separated by comma, followed by a colon, space and then the error message.

```
<FieldName1>, <FieldName2>, <FieldName3>: <ErrorMessage>"
```

**Input Example**

```
"ConsumerSecret, ConsumerKey: Invalid application credentials" 
"Password: Invalid Must contain at least one alpha, one numeric, and one special character"
```

Method

```
string Message GetErrorByField (string FieldName, string InputString);
```

## 1

```
ErrorMessage = GetErrorByField("ConsumerSecret", "ConsumerSecret, ConsumerKey: Invalid application credentials");
```

ErrorMessage should now equal

```
"Invalid application credentials".
```

## 2

```
ErrorMessage = GetErrorByField("ConsumerKey", "ConsumerSecret, ConsumerKey: Invalid application credentials");
```

ErrorMessage should now equal

```
"Invalid application credentials".
```

## 3

```
ErrorMessage = GetErrorByField("Password", "Password: Invalid Must contain at least one alpha, one numeric, and one special character");
```

ErrorMessage should now equal

```
"Invalid Must contain at least one alpha, one numeric, and one special character".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the `InputString` i.e., second parameter in `GetErrorByField()` method by `:` then you will get the result by considering the splitted string with index 1

```
string Message = InputString.Split(':')[1].Trim();
```

Comment: beautiful that works! :D, only thing the first character contains a space.

Comment: Which first character are you telling about.

Comment: So do `InputString.Split(':')[1].Trim();` to trim off whitespace from the start and end.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method of the string class, and get the appropriate value:

```
GetErrorByField(string str)
{
   var splited = str.Split(":".ToCharArray());
   if (splited != null && splited.Length == 2)
      return splited[1].TrimStart().TrimEnd();
   return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: @JeremyMcGee when question wroted at first there wasn't such an example and just says they are comma separated (first field) and `:` separated (second field), by current approach I'd fixed my answer, I wrote this, because OP can obtain everything he wants from different parts (but not currently).